# Third party SDK in Titanium with Hyperloop

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks, titanium, appcelerator

I am using appcelerator titanium 7.0.2 ga sdk and building an ios app. The app is built and functional and now I need to import a third party sdk in order to connect to a 360 camera within my app.

During this attempt at using the 360camera sdk I have started with a blank project and my code attempts below are directly in index.js controller. The app is clean other than this code attempt. So there is nothing else going on to get in the way.

In titanium I am building in a dev environment for ipad ios os v11.2 but the same errors occur in 8.x and 9.x ios os.

Using this guide, 
https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/ios_hyperloop_programming_guide.html
I have successfully imported the sdk for the camera. The app compiles and compilation output confirms the classes were inserted by the compiler. The output is:

```
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCoreMedia/INS3DObject
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSButtonPressOptions
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCoreMedia/INSCamera
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraBTPeripheral
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraCalibrationVignetteGain
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraCalibrationVignetteLuma
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraCaptureStatus
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraDevice
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraDeviceSettings
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraExposureOptions
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraExposureParameter
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraFlatPanoOutput
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraImageStitcher
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class INSCameraSDK/INSCameraManager
```

(Truncated for brevity)

There is very little documentation for the framework I am using but there is a readme that says what to do in swift.

```
import INSCameraSDK`

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    INSCameraManager.shared().setup()
    return true
}

[[INSCameraManager sharedManager] shutdown] //Call this when your app won't listen on Insta360 cameras any more.
```

And inside titanium I am trying to do something like this:

```
var INSCameraSDK = require('INSCameraSDK/INSCameraSDK');   // this does not cause an error when I compile

var mgr = new INSCameraSDK.INSCameraManager(); // causes error  
//"undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new INSCameraSDK.INSCameraManager()')";
```

I also have tried this below:

```
var Manager = require('INSCameraSDK/INSCameraManager');   // this does not cause an error when I compile
var mgr = new Manager();  // this cause an error
mgr.shared().setup(); // this never runs due to above exception
// the error is:
[ERROR] :  Cannot find class with name: INSCameraManager
```

Also, on this link for titanium docs:
https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/ios_hyperloop_programming_guide.html

it says this:

> ## Function pointers
>
> Currently, function pointers are not currently supported in the latest version.

How do I find out if this INSCameraSDK uses function pointers? If the SDK is not using them what am I doing wrong trying to implement it.

Here is some of the .h files from the camera sdk I am trying to use - I thought it might help.

- this is the main INSCameraSDK.h file

  ```
      #import
  ```

  ```
  //! Project version number for INSCameraSDK.
  FOUNDATION_EXPORT double INSCameraSDKVersionNumber;

  //! Project version string for INSCameraSDK.
  FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char INSCameraSDKVersionString[];

  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraPhotoInfo.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraVideoInfo.h>

  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraError.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraManager.h>

  #import INSCameraSDK/NSNotification+INSCamera.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraCommandOptions.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraCommands.h>

  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraMedia.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraMediaSession.h>

  #import INSCameraSDK/INSThumbnailRender.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraPreviewPlayer.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraImageStitcher.h>

  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraFlatPanoOutput.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraScreenOutput.h>
  #import INSCameraSDK/INSCameraRawDataOutput.h>
  </pre>
  ```
- this is the INSCameraManager.h file

  //
      //  INSCameraManager.h
      //  INSCameraSDK
      //

  `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  #import "INSCameraDevice.h"
  #import "INSCameraCommands.h"

  NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

  /// Posted on NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter when an insta360 camera becomes connected and available for your application to use.
  extern NSString *const INSCameraDidConnectNotification;

  /// Posted on NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter when an insta360 camera becomes disconnected.
  extern NSString *const INSCameraDidDisconnectNotification;

  typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, INSCameraState) {
      /// an insta360 camera is found, but not connected, will not response
      INSCameraStateFound,

      /// the nano device is connected, app is able to send requests
      INSCameraStateConnected,

      /// connect failed
      INSCameraStateConnectFailed,

      /// default state, no insta360 camera is found
      INSCameraStateNoConnection,
  };

  @interface INSCameraManager : NSObject

  /**
   *  repsent the current connected nano camera, nil when no camera is connected.
   */
  @property (nonatomic, nullable, readonly) INSCameraDevice *currentCamera;

  /**
   *  all the commands that the camera will handle
   */
  @property (nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) id<INSCameraAllUSBCommands> commandManager;

  /**
   *  NotificationCenter used to receive notifications from camera. See also NSNotification+INSCamera.h
   */
  @property (nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter;

  /**
   *  the current connection state. 
   */
  @property (nonatomic, readonly) INSCameraState cameraState;

  /**
   *  a singleton manager
   */
  + (instancetype)sharedManager;

  /**
   *  setup insta360 camera settings, must be called.
   */
  - (void)setup;

  /**
   *  must be called if you don't want to use insta360 camera any more.
   */
  - (void)shutdown;
  @end
  NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
  </pre>`